# What do each of the powerups do in STRAFE?

Tags: strafe

STRAFE just released a few days ago, and it's freakishly addicting. However, I'm still confused on some parts of the game. Scattered around the maps are small boxes that contain powerups that seem to add modifiers to your character. I don't know what any of these modifiers mean, though, so what are the powerups, and what do they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The community at large seems to have figured out what the powerups do, and these are related to the images that pop up per powerup.

- Red Skull: + Damage
- Yellow Crosshair: + Accuracy
- Blue Bullets: + Ammo Capacity
- Purple Bullets: + Fire Rate

[Information retrieved here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/442780/discussions/0/2741975115064304812/) and from in-game experience.